# Is it possible to insert a row with bold-text after every 10 rows with "normal" text

Tags: html, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

]I have a table where I'm trying to implement pagination with dynamic header, this is why I'm using rows with style: font-weight:bold. they will play role of heaers in my pagination. is it possible to insert every 10 rows one row with font-weight:bold? I'not sure how to do it and what I'm doing wrong here.

here ist what I've done:

```
enter code here
```

https://codepen.io/Dimi98765/pen/yLeawEK

Comment: [mcve] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Please see [ask]: *If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Comment: sorry not really understood how to add links here, but somehow I've made it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: iterate through all rows of the `<tbody>` and use the  [modulus operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) and the [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function to set the class `bold` to every 10th row. In case you want every 11th row to be bold (as you wrote that you want to have a bold row after every 10 rows), just change the line `if(count % 10 === 0)` to `if(count % 11 === 0)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadData();
  $("#calendar tbody tr").each(function() {
    let count = $(this).index() + 1;
    if(count % 10 === 0){
    $(this).addClass("bold");
    }
  });
});

var tableId = "Tabledta";


function LoadData() {
  var tab = $("<table  id=calendar class=MyTable border=1></table>");
  //var thead = $("<thead></thead>");
  var tbody = $('<tbody id="paginate"></tbody>');

  for (var j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
    var theadrow = $('<tr/>');
    theadrow.append('<td style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">FSE' + "&nbsp;" + '</td>');
    theadrow.append('<td style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Monday' + "&nbsp;" + j + '</td>');
    theadrow.append('<td style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Tuesday' + "&nbsp;" + j + '</td>');
    theadrow.append('<td style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Wednesday' + "&nbsp;" + j + '</td>');
    theadrow.append('<td style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Thursday' + "&nbsp;" + j + '</td>');
    theadrow.append('<td style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Friday' + "&nbsp;" + j + '</td>');
    theadrow.append('<td style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Saturday' + "&nbsp;" + j + '</td>');
    theadrow.append('<td style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Sunday' + "&nbsp;" + j + '</td>');
    tab.append(theadrow);

  }



  for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
    var trow = $("<tr/>").data("id", i);
    trow.append("<td>FSE" + i + "</td>");
    trow.append("<td>Monday" + i + "</td>");
    trow.append("<td>Tuesday" + i + "</td>");
    trow.append("<td>Wednesday" + i + "</td>");
    trow.append("<td> Thursday" + i + "</td>");
    trow.append(" <td>Friday" + i + "</td>");
    trow.append("<td>Saturday" + i + "</td>");
    trow.append("<td>Sunday" + i + "</td>");
    tbody.append(trow);
  }


  //tab.append(thead);
  tab.append(tbody);
  $("#" + tableId).html(tab);
}
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=Tabledta></div>
```

Comment: it works ans it's very close to that what i want to do, but I'm changing table data and not pushing rows, what i want to have inbetween

Comment: the idea is to get all days of, let me say, a year, and put them in every week as a header...but i guess its not really possible....

Comment: @Dimitri Sorry but I don't understand what you mean with getting all days of e.g. a year and have them as header. Can you make a table of the first 11 rows with such a header and add it to your question so your desired result is easier to understand?

Comment: @Dimitri And the next header 10 rows later shold then contain the dates 10 weeks later?

Comment: look at my picture above. I'm implementing calendar with a pagination and header is always the same: monday, tuesday, wedneday and so on, but I want to add dates also to a header and have no idea how to implement it. can You understand? I want fill header with some dynamic data

Comment: @Dimitri And this header row that is appearing after every 10 rows should then have the dates 10 weeks later?

Comment: no, on the next page it should be next 7 days of a following week, following to pictire it will be 08.01, 09.01, 10.01 and so on

Comment: @Dimitri But should it be a real calendar? Asking this because the 1.1. was a Wednesday and not a Monday.

Comment: yes should it, it was just for example, to make it more clear

Comment: Here for example one more table: [link](https://codepen.io/Dimi98765/pen/WNrxvPj)

Comment: Here a Fiddle that maybe does what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/9kLzv21y/

Comment: two little question: 1. where did You set the first day 31.12.2019 and 2. how to push first inserted row below the  header row, right after row with "FSE","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"? look: [https://jsfiddle.net/9d4w1csy/](https://jsfiddle.net/9d4w1csy/)

Comment: 1. The first day 30.12.2019 is just the result of getDateRangeOfWeek for the 1st week of 2020 (a function I adjusted and got from here: https://codepen.io/Venugopal46/pen/WrxdLY) . 2. I pushed the first row below the header here: https://jsfiddle.net/f2hqexro/

Comment: okay, now it even better... You are javascript god :)

Comment: have You seen, that it doesn't work with    let items = getDateRangeOfWeek(week, 2022); it returns Year 2021, and Also    let items = getDateRangeOfWeek(week, 2021) returns Year 2020...

Comment: @Dimitri I have it fixed for 2021 and 2022 and all years until 2050 here: https://jsfiddle.net/gje16dby/ The reason is in the function getWeek I have from the mentioned codepen. The line date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7); needs to be adjusted for some years.

Comment: perfect! Thanks one more time!